# React Native (Android): Can't return String in a jobject via JNI

Tags: javascript, android, c++, react-native

I'm trying to (literally) bridge the gap between JavaScript (React Native 0.61.5) and C++ for Android, in order to use OpenCV (3.2.0). Might be noteworthy that I use a deprecated NDK (16) because otherwise I can't use `gnustl_static`.

### The problem

Whenever I try to return a `String` from my native C++ code to Java, the app crashes on the native side. Returning simple data types (in my example, `int`) is not a problem though.

---

### Dev Environment

- macOS Catalina Version `10.15.4 (19E266)`
- React Native Version `0.61.5`
- Android Studio Version `4.0`

  - NDK Version `16.1.4479499`
  - CMake Version `3.6.4111459`

---

### Source Files

#### **`Application.mk`**

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

#### **`index.js`**

The JavaScript side of things, calling the native methods `test()` and `testWithString()`.

```
import {NativeModules, Platform} from "react-native";
const {RNSKOpenCVModule} = NativeModules // RNSKOpenCVModule.java

// success
RNSKOpenCVModule.test(Platform.OS)
.then((result) => console.warn (`RNSKOpenCVModule.test(${Platform.OS}) result: ` + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)))
.catch(console.error)

// error
RNSKOpenCVModule.testWithString(Platform.OS)
.then((result) => console.warn (`RNSKOpenCVModule.testWithString(${Platform.OS}) result: ` + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)))
.catch(console.error)
```

#### **`RNSKOpenCVModule.java`**

Calls the actual C++ methods and returns a `WritableMap`, which can be used as an `Object` in JavaScript.

```
package com.skizzo.opencv;

// imports

public class RNSKOpenCVModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  RNSKOpenCVModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
    reactContext = context;
  }
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib"); // native-lib.cpp
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    Log.w ("opencvtest", "RNSKOpenCVModule.java getName() called");
    return "RNSKOpenCVModule"; // NativeModules.RNSKOpenCVModule
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void test(final String platform, final Promise promise) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    if (currentActivity == null) {
        promise.reject("Activity doesn't exist.");
        return;
    }
    Log.w("RNSKOpenCVModule", "RNSKOpenCVModule.java.test()");
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          StructTestResult testResult = RNSKOpenCVNativeClass.test(platform);
          WritableMap res = testResult.toWritableMap(); 
          promise.resolve(res);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          promise.reject("ERR", e);
        }
      }
    };
    AsyncTask.execute(runnable);
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void testWithString(final String platform, final Promise promise) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
    if (currentActivity == null) {
      promise.reject("Activity doesn't exist.");
      return;
    }
    Log.w("RNSKOpenCVModule", "RNSKOpenCVModule.java.testWithString()");
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          StructTestWithStringResult testWithStringResult = RNSKOpenCVNativeClass.testWithString(platform);
          WritableMap res = testWithStringResult.toWritableMap(); 
          promise.resolve(res);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          promise.reject("ERR", e);
        }
      }
    };
    AsyncTask.execute(runnable);
  }

}
```

#### `native-lib.cpp`

```
#include <android/log.h>

#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define LOG_TAG "native-lib"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGW(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PLATFORM_OPENCV_ANDROID
#ifdef PLATFORM_OPENCV_ANDROID
  #define printf(...) __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "SKOpenCv", __VA_ARGS__);
#endif

typedef struct {
  int testInt;
} StructTestResult, *pStructTestResult;

typedef struct {
  int testInt;
  char* testString;
} StructTestWithStringResult, *pStructTestWithStringResult;

extern "C"
{
  // StructTestResult
  jclass STRUCT_TEST_RESULT;
  jmethodID STRUCT_TEST_RESULT_CONSTRUCTOR;
  jfieldID STRUCT_TEST_RESULT_TESTINT;

  // StructTestWithStringResult
  jclass STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT;
  jmethodID STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_CONSTRUCTOR;
  jfieldID STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_TESTINT;
  jfieldID STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_TESTSTRING;

  jclass JAVA_EXCEPTION;

  jint JNI_OnLoad (JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) { // called once onLoad
    JNIEnv *env;

    if (vm->GetEnv((void **) (&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
      return -1;
    }

    // StructTestResult
    STRUCT_TEST_RESULT              = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef (env->FindClass("com/skizzo/opencv/StructTestResult"));
    STRUCT_TEST_RESULT_CONSTRUCTOR  = env->GetMethodID (STRUCT_TEST_RESULT, "<init>", "(I)V");
    STRUCT_TEST_RESULT_TESTINT      = env->GetFieldID (STRUCT_TEST_RESULT, "testInt", "I");

    // StructTestWithStringResult
    STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT              = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef (env->FindClass("com/skizzo/opencv/StructTestWithStringResult"));
    STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_CONSTRUCTOR  = env->GetMethodID (STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT, "<init>", "(ILjava/lang/String;)V");
    STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_TESTINT      = env->GetFieldID (STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT, "testInt", "I");
    STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_TESTSTRING   = env->GetFieldID (STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT, "testString", "Ljava/lang/String;");

    // Exception
    JAVA_EXCEPTION = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef (env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception"));

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
  }

  jobject JNICALL Java_com_skizzo_opencv_RNSKOpenCVNativeClass_test (JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring platform) {
    const char* platformStr = env->GetStringUTFChars (platform, NULL);
    LOGD("platformStr: %s", platformStr); // "android"

    StructTestResult testResult;
    testResult.testInt = 123; // int -> OK

    // turn the C struct back into a jobject and return it
    return env->NewObject(STRUCT_TEST_RESULT, STRUCT_TEST_RESULT_CONSTRUCTOR, testResult.testInt);
  }

  jobject JNICALL Java_com_skizzo_opencv_RNSKOpenCVNativeClass_testWithString (JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jstring platform) {
    const char* platformStr = env->GetStringUTFChars (platform, NULL);
    LOGD("platformStr: %s", platformStr); // "android"

    StructTestWithStringResult testWithStringResult;
    testWithStringResult.testInt = 456; // int -> OK

    char* openCvVersion = CV_VERSION;
    LOGD("openCvVersion: %s", openCvVersion);

    testWithStringResult.testString = CV_VERSION; // adding this line produces the crash

    // turn the C struct back into a jobject and return it
    return env->NewObject(STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT, STRUCT_TEST_WITH_STRING_RESULT_CONSTRUCTOR, testWithStringResult.testInt, testWithStringResult.testString);
  }

}
```

#### `StructTestResult.java`

```
package com.skizzo.opencv;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;

public class StructTestResult {

  int testInt;

  public StructTestResult () {}

  public StructTestResult (int testInt) {
    this.testInt = testInt;
  }

  public StructTestResult (ReadableMap map) {
    this (
      (int)map.getDouble("testInt")
    );
  }

  public WritableMap toWritableMap() {
    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
    map.putInt("testInt", this.testInt);
    return map;
  }
}
```

#### `StructTestWithStringResult.java`

```
package com.skizzo.opencv;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;

public class StructTestWithStringResult {

  int testInt;
  String testString;

  public StructTestWithStringResult () {}

  public StructTestWithStringResult (int testInt, String testString) {
    this.testInt = testInt;
    // this.testString = "testFromJavaConstructor"; // success
    this.testString = testString; // error
  }

  public StructTestWithStringResult (ReadableMap map) {
    this (
      (int)map.getDouble("testInt"),
      map.getString("testString")
    );
  }

  public WritableMap toWritableMap() {
    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();
    map.putInt("testInt", this.testInt);
    map.putString("testString", this.testString);
    return map;
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm really stuck here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`testWithStringResult.testString` is a member of a struct and is of character array type. The memory against the variable is not allocated yet. You have to allocate the memory first and then perform the strcpy() operation. Here is the code block you can try by replacing your troublesome line.

```
testWithStringResult.testString = new char(strlen(CV_VERSION));
strcpy(testWithStringResult.testString, CV_VERSION);
```

Hope it will solve the problem. If not, please provide the crash log.